# Get coordinates of a free hand drawn polyline by user. (ArcGIS API for JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, dictionary, coordinates, arcgis, polyline

I'm new here, and I have been using the ArcGIS javascript api for about 2 weeks now.

I have followed this example:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/graphics_add

And I was able to draw a free hand polyline on the map. Now I need to calculate the coordinates of every single point on that polyline. I have been trying to do it for about 5 days now and I can't figure out how to do it. I would appreciate if any of you could explain me how to do it in detail (since I don't have too much experience with it).

Thanks in advance,

Diego.

Comment: 404. Did you mean to link to http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/graphics_add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inspect the `geometry` object you get from the event onDrawEnd - this event is already being hooked in the example:

`dojo.connect(tb, "onDrawEnd", addGraphic);`

but all it does is add the line to the map with an basic symbol. The first trap is that the geometry object won't actually be of type `geometry` - that's an abstract base class that doesn't really exist. The type will depend on what tool you were using to draw the shape - in your case it sounds like it'll be of type [`Polyline`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/#polyline).

This Polyline object has a property [`paths`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/#Polyline/paths), which is a nested array of paths (lines), each of which contains an array of points. So if you wanted to get all the points of all the paths in a Polyline object:

```
function addGraphic(geo) {
    //For each path...
    for ( var path = 0; path < geo.paths.length; path ++ ) {
        //For each point in the path...
        for ( var pt = 0; pt < geo.paths[path].length; pt++ ) {
            //Do something with each point in here...
            //X coordinate: geo.paths[path][pt][0]
            //Y coordinate: geo.paths[path][pt][1]
        }
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to do some more checks on things like whether you actually have a Polyline, or some other object that inherits from `geometry`, since the property that contains the actual coordinates varies between Polyline, Polygon, Point etc.

Comment: No worries. If you click the tick mark next to the answer, everyone gets a free kitten. :)

Comment: In which format are the coordinates, screen units or map units?

Comment: Never mind, just found a way to convert it to geographic coordinates, I just needed to add: geo = esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(geo);

Comment: Good work. As you've probably noticed, the coordinates will come back in the SpatialReference of your map - which in most (all?) cases is going to be Web Mercator. If you ever get strange results when playing with geometries, the first thing to check is whether you're playing in the right SR. :)